# Cannot find module '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am trying to install and use `camera-preview` [from Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview) in the same way as I did for the other plugin `camera`. While it works for `camera`, I seem not to be able to redo the same for `camera-preview`.

I installed it as follows:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera-preview
npm install --save @ionic-native/camera-preview
```

And then integrated it in my code as follow:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { CameraPreview } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx';

// ...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    CameraPreview,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { CameraPreview } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx';

// ...

export class HomePage {

  public image = '';

  constructor(private cameraPreview: CameraPreview) {

  }


}
```

When running `ionic serve -c` I receive the errors:

> [ng] ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(12,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx'.
>
> [ng] src/app/home/home.page.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx'.

What is going on?

Comment: which Ionic version you have?

Comment: How can you check that?

Comment: can u share your package.json and ionic info result?

Comment: @JohnAndrews you can check with following command in terminal "ionic version"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed ngx from the plugin like:

from:

```
import { CameraPreview } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx';
```

to:

```
import { CameraPreview } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview';
```

and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, make sure you have the latest version of Ionic and Ionic-Native installed. Ionic 3 and early versions of 4 don't work with the ngx imports.

If you are on a later version (4.x or 5), then clean your node_modules folder and reinstall everything, including the camera plugin.